# Let p be an odd prime with $(a,p) = 1$ and $(\frac{a}{p})$ = 1. show that $x^2$ ≡ a (mod p)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-reciprocity

Let p be an odd prime with $(a,p) = 1$ and $(\frac{a}{p})$ = 1. show that $x^2$ ≡ a (mod p) has precisely two incongruent solutions mod p.

- Having a bit of trouble with this question, we are currently covering a section on quadratic reciprocity and didn't really see anything in my notes that helped me solve this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where $x$ is.....? Also, your last three questions now have the exact same comment (that makes up most of the question) about your notes not having anything relevant. Perhaps it's time to go and read your book's section on quadratic reciprocity, as well as speak with the professor about strategies for these sorts of problems.

Comment: I'm currently doing review on this, I did all the problems I could and now finishing up left overs, I am sorry if my comments are repetitive but i just want to finish my review in time for midterms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the condition $(a/p)=1$ *includes* $(a,p)=1$.

Saying that $(a/p)=1$ says that $a$ is a quadratic residue of $p$.

So by definition if $(a/p)=1$ then the congruence $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ has at least one solution, say $b$. We will show that it has exactly two solutions.

First note that if $b^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$, then $(-b)^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$. Note also that if $p$ is odd, then $b\not\equiv -b\pmod{p}$. So if $(a/p)=1$ then the congruence $x^2\equiv a \pmod{p}$ has at least two solutions. It remains to show there are no more than two.

If $b$ is a solution, and $x$ is any solution, then $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ and $b^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$, and therefore $x^2\equiv b^2\pmod{p}$.

Thus $(x-b)(x+b)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. So $p$ divides the product $(x-b)(x+b)$, and therefore $p$ must divide one of the terms (Euclid's Lemma). It follows that $x\equiv b\pmod{p}$ or $x\equiv -b\pmod{p}$, so there are only two solutions.